# lsusb does not show my plugged in usb device

Tags: external-hdd, lsusb

lsusb shows usb device when I boot from USB and select "Try ubuntu" but lsusb does not show my usb devices when I boot up in the full installation of Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide some more information.